# Can't change the selected item of a WPF listview if it has focus

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm struggeling a bit on a private WPF project. I have a Listview with a bound viewmodel. For the most listview items i display a detail page on the right side depending on the selected listview item. But for one scenario i only would like to do some action after selecting the item and then automatically selecting the item which was selected before. Altough in the viewmodel the selected item property changes correctly, the view keeps the former selected item focused.

I created a minimum example where i just select the first item again, if the user selected any other item. This should be sufficient to talk about my problem:

ViewModels:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private TestItem _selectedItem;
        public ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items { get; set; }

        public TestItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (value != null && Items.IndexOf(value) != 0)
                {
                    SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
            Items.Add(new TestItem("a"));
            Items.Add(new TestItem("b"));
            Items.Add(new TestItem("c"));
        }
    }

    public class TestItem : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public TestItem(string name)
        {
            Name = name;

        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestItem}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Currently i'm out of ideas why this doesn't work. Usually if WPF does anything unexpected i would have expected to see that after i set my selected item WPF overwrites it again but that doesn't happen. In the viewmodel everything works fine but the view doesn't synchronize with the viewmodel. I also attached

```
diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High
```

Property to the binding, but i couldn't find anything useful there. Perhaps i'm blind at the moment.

Comment: [Obviously](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hjk2D2)

Comment: You are not calling `OnPropertyChanged` after `SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();`. Maybe this is your issue.

Comment: Yeah the equals method doesn't return true if I create the object twice with the same constructor parameter. But in my case i take the object from the same list. There the Equals method returns true.

OnPropertyChanged gets called implicitly by setting the SelectedItem via property setter so this seems not to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i don't know why but using a different task like this

```
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        SelectedItem = Items[0];
                    });
                });
```

did the trick.